How to set the flash strength when taking photos with Camera2
I am trying to maximize the flash strength when taking photos with a Pixel7a by camera2 API.
When I set the flash strength using turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(), the torch turns on from the start of the preview.
I'd like to know whether there is a way to set the flash strength only when taking a photo.
Thanks in advance.

Please, provide more code and details about the problem! If it's possible in this order: what you want, what you did, what you expect from your code and what it's going wrong. Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Andre Carneiro-san,
Thank you for reply.
I also posted the same message to the cameraX community and got a reply as follows:
https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/I-JjZww6BB8/m/_8u8biv3AAAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer
The function will be added in Android15, so I'll wait until then.
Thank you for your kind answer anyway.
Regards,
